# Error while installing phonegap 3.0 CLI using npm

Tags: cordova, command-line-interface, npm

I keep getting the following error while trying to install phonegap 3.0 using cli
Can you please help me figure out where I am going wrong?
I am using a Macbook Pro

```
~ developer$ sudo npm install g- phonegap
npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/g-
npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/g-
npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/g-
npm http GET https: //registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "g-" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/developer
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.21
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/developer/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: I am not working behind proxy, still i am getting the same error while installing `phonegap`, Can anyone help me out.

Comment: As of 3.3.0 it is recommended to install phonegap using the Cordova flavour `sudo npm install -g cordova`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your proxy settings are not correct. Perhaps you are using npm from behind a proxy server and hence you need update the proxy settings of npm. For doing so you can follow the link http://wil.boayue.com/blog/2013/06/14/using-npm-behind-a-proxy/. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the only problem, but

```
sudo npm install g- phonegap
```

should be

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```